# jQuery + Boostrap DatePicker: How to have two datepicker inputs update each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [this Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) tool in a project, and I have two datepicker fields. I need to have it so that when you select a date in one, it updates the other one to be the same date.

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="date1">
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="date2">

<script>
  $("#date1").datepicker();
  $("#date2").datepicker();
</script>
```

Here is some jQuery to update it:

```
$("#date1").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#date2").datepicker("update", value);
});

$("#date2").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#date1").datepicker("update", value);
});
```

However, the `datepicker('update', value)` function causes the `change` event to fire again, causing an infinite loop. What is the correct/right way to do have this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
var update1 = false;
var update2 = false;

$("#date1").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (!update1) {
    update2 = true;
    $("#date2").datepicker("update", value);
  }

  update1 = false;
});

$("#date2").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (!update2) {
    update1 = true;
    $("#date1").datepicker("update", value);
  }

  update2 = false;
});
```

This does what I want it to, but I'm not sure if it's the correct/best way to do it.

Comment: It looks like you have the best solution for this datepicker library.

Answer (score 0):

I found change event problematic. What I did was to use .on instead.

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', dateToday);
$('#datepicker2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    toDate = $('#datepicker2').val().toString();
    if (toDate < fromDate) {
        fromDate = (new Date(toDate).getMonth() + 1) + "/01/" + new  Date(toDate).getFullYear();
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker('setDate', fromDate);
    }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, apparently there's a big recursion problem with `bootstrap-datepicker`, which does not affect jQuery UI Datepicker. The following code works and prevents recursion, but the `changeDate` event still fires 3 or 4 times.

```js
function datePickerInit(sel) {
  sel = $(sel);
  $(sel).each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker().on("change", function() {
      console.log("change date");
      sel.datepicker("remove");
      sel.siblings(".datepicker").val($(this).val());
      setTimeout(function() {
        datePickerInit(".datepicker");
      }, 100);
    });
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  datePickerInit(".datepicker");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="date1">
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="date2">
```

Comment: But the problem is, I need `#date1` to also update when `#date2` changes as well.

Comment: The issue with updating with `val()` is that is doesn't actually update the value of the datepicker, just the text in the field.

Comment: It does, actually. If you click on the updated date input after it was changed programmatically, the selected date will be the one set in the other date input.

Comment: Ahh, I see. This seems to work for the JQuery UI Datepicker, but not for the Bootstrap Datepicker I have linked.

Comment: Just updated my approach, but you were right, there seems to be a recursion problem with `bootstrap-datepicker`. I tried to remove datepicker on change but the `changeDate` event still fires 3 or 4 times, so your approach using a variable external to the function might actually be better, after all, :-)